# Convert JavaScript into Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

hi im pretty much a beginner.I need some help turning this script in an browser extension for firefox.

The script:

```
window.onload = function () {
  setInterval(function(){
    window.open( "http://www.google.com/" );
  }, 3000);
};
```

*I know this would be inconvenient to the users,its just experimental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to start your Firefox extension development by following this guide: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_started_with_extension_development - it will get you the simplest extension.

Then, to hook your JavaScript to page load event you follow this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load

Comment: Could you please give me an example for my script?

Comment: The example from the second link does `if(doc.location.href.search("forum") > -1) alert("a forum page is loaded");`, you will just need to replace it with `doc.defaultView.location.href="http://www.google.com/"`