# Can we create browser extension for firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

i tried to write a script which can be added as an extension to the browser. The problem with this script is how to access the dom elements of a webpage. i used XMLHttpRequest object for accessing the web page but it has same origin policy issues. I worked on it for nearly 3 weeks finally i used Anyorigin.com code but i am not able to get all the functionality so i thought of using userscript where we can easily access the web page's DOM elements. Is ther any other way to create an extension

Comment: Duplicate of [How To Create a Quick Minimal Firefox Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/274639/331508) and also [Convert JavaScript into Firefox extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9234642/331508).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While enloz's answers are good, Firefox has an [Add-on Builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) that you can you use.

Add-ons are built using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. There is a web based version with the following features (quoting from their website):

> - Edit code in a feature-rich environment
> - Test your add-ons instantly
> - Use built-in version control & sharing

You can find the web based version here: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> **Greasemonkey:** 
>   Customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by
>   using small bits of JavaScript.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

---

**Update**:

This looks to be a better solution, but I haven't tested it.

http://crossrider.com/

Comment: Yes Now i am creating userscripts but for this we have to download Greasmonkey that is why i am asking is there any other alternative

Comment: I even tried converting userscript to firefox extension using [Userscript Complier](https://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler.php) but it didn't work